# "Shadowbox is not defined" error which suggests that Shadowbox.init(shadowbox_conf)?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, shadowbox

I am having a problem where i am getting the error "Shadowbox is not defined" and it suggests that Shadowbox.init(shadowbox_conf) is the problem.

I believe that this issue started occurring when I updated from wordpress 3.3.0 to 3.3.1.

I can't figure out why this has suddenly started to cause a problem. Unfortunately my javascript skills are lacking, so any help you could give me would be appreciated.

You can view the page in question here. (note I am using shadowbox JS plugin to use the shadowbox lightbox, and I have also integrated this with the javascript plugin isotope, which is use for layout and filtering.

http://www.imageworkshop.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, i eventually tracked down the fix.
I am using the Shadowbox JS plugin. Turns out that this plugin has been removed from the repository at wordpress, and i had missed out on the latest update which fixed the compatibility issues. Follow the link below to find out more and download teh latest version if you require.

http://sivel.net/2011/12/shadowbox-js-plugin-pulled-from-the-wordpress-org-repository/